# Keep intentional indentations in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, indentation

I am declaring a bunch of variables for a ribbon bar, and I want to **indent** them so they reflect the actual hierarchy. My code looks like this:

```
protected C1.Win.C1Ribbon.C1Ribbon rib;
    public C1.Win.C1Ribbon.RibbonTab rib_tabMain;
        public C1.Win.C1Ribbon.RibbonGroup rib_grpClipboard;
            public C1.Win.C1Ribbon.RibbonButton rib_btnCut;
            public C1.Win.C1Ribbon.RibbonSplitButton rib_btnSplitCopy;
                public C1.Win.C1Ribbon.RibbonButton rib_btnCopyPlain;
                public C1.Win.C1Ribbon.RibbonButton rib_btnCopyWithHeaders;
            public C1.Win.C1Ribbon.RibbonButton rib_btnPaste;
```

However, when I copy/paste this code to another place, then Visual Studio destroys all indentations. What can I do that Visual Studio is keeping the indentations?

Comment: Your example doesn't looks like something what can be defined as a rule (nor I like your idea of indenting), therefore you have only option to turn indentation completely off. See [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+vs+turn+off+indents+site:stackoverflow.com), the suitable answer depends on version of VS.

Comment: [use comment for this](https://pastebin.com/LDUGqwbB) ... *Visual Studio destroys all indentations* and that's good ... it's hard to read **badly** formated code

Comment: *"My code is much clearer with indentations"* - nope, it's not. What you are trying to do is to save hierarchy somehow amoung fields. As @Selvin mentioned, comments are the right way to do so.

Comment: It might be clear to you as the creator, but indentation *generally* gives a hint about scope. If I was about to maintain code like this, I would be thoroughly confused and wipe out the indentation when I made my changes. This just isn't standard, and you should think about the other developers who may someday be in this code.

Comment: @askolotl, I assume you are working alone. In the team your code will not pass code review because of formatting, naming, etc. Consider to make standards and guidelines your habbit.

Comment: @askolotl - then you should definitely be *more* inclined to follow standards, if anything. I've left otherwise good workplaces because of poor standards (although I will say, they were **very** poor). Lead by (good) example.

Comment: @askolotl is onto something because I wanted to do the same thing with Swing elements.

Comment: @BálintJuhász I think you can then see the hierarchy of the elements better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you insert (Ctrl + V), hit Undo once (Ctrl + Z). The first undo will only effect the formatting that Visual Studio applied automatically.